# GAE: file_get_contents() and static files

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-php

Instead of updating the same variable in various locations I parse files and extract the bits I need. One bit I am looking for is the cache name in my service-worker.js file. When I'm developing locally, I can easily retrieve the js file in the directory structure.

When I deploy my app to GAE, the service worker JS file needs to be declared static and so GAE stashes it away somewhere.

Is there a way to get to this file without making a URL call?

This is what I currently use and it's all working fine in DEV:

```
<?php
function getCacheId() {
    $cache_id = "";
    $c = file_get_contents ( dirname ( __FILE__ ) . "/service-worker.js" );
    if (preg_match ( "/CACHE_NAME = '(.*)'/", $c, $matches ) !== false) {
        if (count ( $matches )) {
            $cache_id = trim ( $matches[1] );
        }
    }
    return $cache_id;
}
?>
<script>
    const CACHEID = "<?php echo getCacheId() ?>";
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to also configure `application_readable: true` in addition to the static file declaration in your `app.yaml` file.

From [Handlers element](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appref#handlers_element):

> **application_readable**
>
> Optional. Boolean. By default, files declared in static file handlers
>   are uploaded as static data and are only served to end users. They
>   cannot be read by an application. If this field is set to true, the
>   files are also uploaded as code data so your application can read
>   them. Both uploads are charged against your code and static data
>   storage [resource quotas](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Code).