# how to open a file in python in google app engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

```
 new_file = open('../pages/pdf/test.PDF', 'rb').read()
```

keeps giving me file/directory not found

I also tried this in my app.yaml :

```
 - url: /test.((pdf)|(PDF))
   static_files: pages/pdf/test.PDF
   upload: pages/pdf/test.PDF
```

File structure

```
 -app.yaml
 pages
   -index.html
   -page1.html
   pdf
     -test.PDF
 entities
   -booking.py (file that im writing the above code)
```

how to properly open a file in google app engine?

Here are the app.yaml handlers

```
 - url: /sitemap.xml
   script: sitemap.app

 - url: /test.((pdf)|(PDF))
   static_files: pages/pdf/test.PDF
   upload: pages/pdf/test.PDF
   application_readable: true

 - url: /images
   static_dir: pages/images

 - url: /fonts
   static_dir: pages/fonts

 - url: /css
   static_dir: pages/css
   expiration: 1s
```

Trying to attach the above file as below using EmailMessage :

```
 new_file = open(os.path.dirname(__file__) +'/../pages/pdf/test.PDF').read()

 message = mail.EmailMessage( sender=EMAIL_SENDER, 
 subject=subject,body=theBody,to=['myemail@gmail.com'],attachments= 
 [('test',new_file)])

 message.send()
```

In debuggin it says : Invalid attachment type

Comment: Is the file included with your application? If so where is it located relative to your `app.yaml` file?

Comment: @DanCornilescu please see my update added file structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default files included in your app's static content (i.e. matching a `static_files` or `static_dir` handler configuration pattern) aren't accessible to your application code. If you want such access you need to set the `application_readable: true` option for the respective `app.yaml` handler configurations. See [GAE: file_get_contents() and static files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41414346/gae-file-get-contents-and-static-files/41414501#41414501)

Once you do that the file will be accessible using a path relative to your application/service root directory (i.e. where the `app.yaml` file is located), in your case it'll be `pages/pdf/test.PDF`.

Comment: thxxx! @Dan Cornilescu open('pages/pdf/test.PDF', 'rb').read(), but I still get invalid file for some reason even after adding application_readable: true

Comment: can you pls update the post with all the static handler configs deployed?

Comment: Added app.yaml handlers. btw shouldn't it be ('../pages/pdf/test.PDF','rb') instead of ('pages/pdf/test.PDF','rb'). as the current file is inside entities?

Comment: Hm, it *should* work :) The only other thing that crosses my mind would be case (in)sensitivity in the file name/path. Check your actually deployed files, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47498821/google-cloud-datastore-automatic-indexing/47499884#47499884

Comment: Files *should* be accessible from the app's root dir, without the `../` in your case - at least that's how imports work. But give the `../` a try as well, just in case I'm wrong.

Comment: BTW - is the same working with your development server?

Comment: this is actually in the development server :D and we are stuck...it seems like the file is properly being linked with the ../ . thanks a lot!! but the final step of us trying to link this file is to send it as an attachment. It keeps saying invalid attachment ><

Comment: Is the file actually a (sym)link? That could be the issue on the development server (depending on how exactly the file is symlinked and  used). When deployed the symlinks are replaced with actual copies of the files they're pointing to, so such issues would not be seen on GAE.

Comment: I not am sure about sym link, I have added the EmailMessage where I am trying to add as an attachment

Comment: Don't mix the email attachment with this question, that's most likely a different issue - I see you already have a separate question for that. You can check that your file is readable with a temporary `logging.info(new_file)` statement.